# Adjust position of dropdownwidth in spark combobox when dataprovider changes

Tags: apache-flex

I am using property popUpWidthMatchesAnchorWidth="false" in combobbox skin to set maximum width of dropdown.
In this everytime updating dataprovider on user types in combobox.whenever dataprovider changes,dropdown width is not adjusting to maximum width and also not positioning properly.

On Dataprovider change I want to set dropdown width to maximum width of the element and also align position of dropdown properly.

```
    [HostComponent("spark.components.ComboBox")]
    ]]>
</fx:Metadata> 

<fx:Script fb:purpose="styling">
    <![CDATA[       
        private var paddingChanged:Boolean;
        private var cornerRadiusChanged:Boolean;
        private var cornerRadius:Number = 0;            
        static private const contentFill:Array = ["bgFill"];
        override public function get contentItems():Array { return contentFill };

        override protected function commitProperties():void
        {
            super.commitProperties();

            if (paddingChanged && textInput)
            {

                var padding:Number;

                padding = getStyle("paddingLeft");
                if (textInput.getStyle("paddingLeft") != padding)
                    textInput.setStyle("paddingLeft", padding);

                padding = getStyle("paddingTop");
                if (textInput.getStyle("paddingTop") != padding)
                    textInput.setStyle("paddingTop", padding);

                padding = getStyle("paddingRight");
                if (textInput.getStyle("paddingRight") != padding)
                    textInput.setStyle("paddingRight", padding);

                padding = getStyle("paddingBottom");
                if (textInput.getStyle("paddingBottom") != padding)
                    textInput.setStyle("paddingBottom", padding);
                paddingChanged = false;
            }

            if (cornerRadiusChanged)
            {
                cornerRadiusChanged = false;
            }
        }

        override public function styleChanged(styleProp:String):void
        {
            var allStyles:Boolean = !styleProp || styleProp == "styleName";

            super.styleChanged(styleProp);

            if (allStyles || styleProp.indexOf("padding") == 0)
            {
                paddingChanged = true;
                invalidateProperties();
            }
            if (allStyles || styleProp == "cornerRadius")
            {
                cornerRadiusChanged = true;
                invalidateProperties();
            }                
        }


        override protected function updateDisplayList(unscaledWidth:Number, unscaledHeight:Number):void
        {
            if (getStyle("borderVisible") == false)
            {
                if (border)
                    border.visible = false;
                if (background)
                {
                    background.left = background.top = background.right = background.bottom = 0;
                }
                if (scroller)
                    scroller.minViewportInset = 0;
            }
            else
            {
                if (border)
                    border.visible = true;
                if (background)
                {
                    background.left = background.top = background.right = background.bottom = 1;
                }
                if (scroller)
                    scroller.minViewportInset = 1;
            }

            if (dropShadow)
                dropShadow.visible = getStyle("dropShadowVisible");



            if (borderStroke)
            {
                borderStroke.color = getStyle("borderColor");
                borderStroke.alpha = getStyle("borderAlpha");
            }
            super.updateDisplayList(unscaledWidth, unscaledHeight);
        }
    ]]>
</fx:Script>

<s:states>
    <s:State name="normal" />
    <s:State name="open" />
    <s:State name="disabled" />
</s:states>


<s:PopUpAnchor id="popUp"  displayPopUp.normal="false" displayPopUp.open="true" includeIn="open"
               left="0" right="0" top="0" bottom="0" itemDestructionPolicy="auto"
               popUpPosition="below" popUpWidthMatchesAnchorWidth="false">


    <s:Group id="dropDown" maxHeight="112" minHeight="22" minWidth="{this.width}">


        <s:RectangularDropShadow id="dropShadow" blurX="20" blurY="20" alpha="0.45" distance="7" 
                                 angle="90" color="#000000" left="0" top="0" right="0" bottom="0"/>


        <s:Rect id="border" left="0" right="0" top="0" bottom="0">
            <s:stroke>

                <s:SolidColorStroke id="borderStroke" weight="1"/>
            </s:stroke>
        </s:Rect>


        <s:Rect id="background" left="1" right="1" top="1" bottom="1" >
            <s:fill>

                <s:SolidColor id="bgFill" color="0xFFFFFF" />
            </s:fill>
        </s:Rect>


        <s:Scroller id="scroller" left="0" top="0" right="0" bottom="0" hasFocusableChildren="false" minViewportInset="1">

            <s:DataGroup id="dataGroup" itemRenderer="spark.skins.spark.DefaultItemRenderer">
                <s:layout>
                    <s:VerticalLayout gap="0" horizontalAlign="contentJustify" requestedMinRowCount="1" requestedMaxRowCount="6"/>
                </s:layout>
            </s:DataGroup> 
        </s:Scroller>
    </s:Group>
</s:PopUpAnchor>


<s:Button id="openButton" width="19" right="0" top="0" bottom="0" focusEnabled="false"
          skinClass="spark.skins.spark.ComboBoxButtonSkin" tabEnabled="false" />  

<s:TextInput id="textInput" enabled.disabled="false"
             left="0" right="18" top="0" bottom="0" 
             skinClass="spark.skins.spark.ComboBoxTextInputSkin"/>
```

Comment: That is not a documented property or style on the Flex 4.6 DropDownList: http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/spark/components/DropDownList.html .  Was it added to Adobe Flex?  If not; what component are you using?  How are you setting this property?

Comment: popUpWidthMatchesAnchorWidth property I am setting in skin class of dropdownlist(popupanchor).Default popUpWidthMatchesAnchorWidth is true,for my requirement i changed to false.When my dropdownlist component is right side of the stage and continuously changing dataprovider,this time dropdown is not aligninig properly.

Comment: Then I'll add that popUpWidthMatchesAnchorWidth is not a property or style documented on the DropDownListSkin class: http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/spark/skins/spark/DropDownListSkin.html

Comment: sorry.I am using combobox.

Comment: There is no property named popUpWidthMatchesAnchorWidth on the Flex ComboBox http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/spark/components/ComboBox.html or on the ComboBoxSkin http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/spark/skins/spark/ComboBoxSkin.html

Comment: This piece of code present in combobox skin              <s:PopUpAnchor id="popUp"  displayPopUp.normal="false" displayPopUp.open="true" includeIn="open"
                   left="0" right="0" top="0" bottom="0" itemDestructionPolicy="auto"
                   popUpPosition="below" popUpWidthMatchesAnchorWidth="false"> I am overriding skin class

Comment: I understand then.  Please edit your question and share your custom skin.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whenever dataprovider changes on combobox text input change,has to use this code, to set position of dropdown in combobox.

LayoutManager.getInstance().validateNow();

(this.skin as ComboBoxSkin).popUp.updatePopUpTransform();